# How do I install Handbrake?

Tags: software-installation, handbrake

I've added the ppa here

[https://edge.launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases](https://edge.launchpad.net/%7Estebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases)

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, the software sources aren't found. I figured maybe they hadn't updated their repos to the newest version, so I changed the distro in Software Center to natty.

Now when I try to install `handbrake-gtk` I get the message

> handbrake-gtk : Depends: libnotify1 (>= 0.5.0) but it is not installable
>
> Depends: libnotify1-gtk2.10 but it is not installable

It looks like the only packages starting with `libnotify` are

```
libnotify0.4-cil
libnotify-bin
libnotify-dev
libnotify4
libnotify-cil-dev
libnotify-doc
```

The only relevant one seemed like `libnotify4`, which is already installed. The CLI version installs fine.

How can I install Handbrake?

Comment: After adding the PPA, `sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk` worked for me on 11.04. Didn't find any instructions on how to actually install it on the PPA page, only how to add the PPA: https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases

Comment: We may be soon going to have handbrake in Debian proper and, therefore, its derivatives, like Ubuntu, are likely to get it. By "we may have handbrake", I mean that I am working to have it properly packaged, which is not a very simple endeavour, as it uses a lot of patched auxiliary programs. Help is welcome in packaging: http://anonscm.debian.org/gitweb/?p=pkg-multimedia/handbrake.git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=libnotify
Get it from here. You need libnotify1 v0.5 or newer.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that libnotify4 would succeed libnotify1, but I guess not. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Here is how to install the official releases, not the snapshots

```
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-cli
```

You can then run it with:

```
HandBrakeCLI --help
```

Answer (score 6):

Installation (original instructions [available here](http://pasindudps.blogspot.com/2011/11/install-handrake-in-ubuntu-1110-oneiric.html))

First thing that you have to do is to add the official PPA - there are [instructions on how to add a PPA here on Ask Ubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) The PPA you want to add is:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally the installation:

`sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk handbrake-cli`

Comment: The ppa in your answer should not be used. That is for unstable handbrake builds. It's described on [this page.](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-snapshots) where it warns you against using it. In general users it's better to follow the instructions in my question and use [the release ppa](https://edge.launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases) and change the version from oneiric to natty.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative: install latest development release of HandBrake from [HandBrake Snapshots PPA](https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-snapshots), that contains also oneiric packages, with all right dependecies: **ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots**

Answer (score 2):

### Ubuntu 14.04 and later

Handbrake is in the default repositories of Ubuntu 14.04 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install handbrake
```

To install the CLI version of Handbrake open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install handbrake-cli
```

Handbrake can be installed as a snap package in Ubuntu 14.04 and later. To find the handbrake snap package open the terminal and type:

```
snap find handbrake # the next 2 lines are the results of the command
Name          Version  Developer  Notes  Summary
handbrake-jz  1.0.2-0  jz         -      The open source video transcoder
```

The results of `snap find handbrake` will usually show that the version of handbrake-jz is the latest stable version of Handbrake. To install this handbrake snap package run these commands:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install handbrake-jz
```

handbrake and handbrake-jz can also be installed from the Ubuntu Software app in Ubuntu 16.04 and later.