# Is there an easy to use video encoder?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I would like to know whether is there an all-in-one application to encode crop resize and mux video files (something like [MeGui](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/) for windows) for ubuntu.

I don't feel like study too hard to learn how to use ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

The reason `ffmpeg`, `mencoder`, et al still exist (and are still so popular) is because if you do learn them, you get the best results. I'm not going to bash on about that but if you find you're not getting good results, you might want to learn a little bit and see if that improves things.

Anyway. [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) is my go-to transcoer. It's just a GUI for various encoders and it "just works" 99% of the time. The best thing I find over applications like Transmageddon (and a billion other one-click transcoders) is you can actually tweak things pretty well, queue them up and leave everything going over night.

- [How do I install Handbrake?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71128/how-do-i-install-handbrake)

Comment: Thank you! Are you aware of any guide for starter about ffmpeg or mencoder? I tried with handbrake once but I have some problems when i try to obtain a dual track audio (i'm italian so I usually want to have italian audio, but I also like to watch movies in their original language). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Handbrake can handle multiple audio tracks if you select the MKV container. If I were you I would just play around with Handbrake's settings and encode a single chapter until you know you've got the right settings. The presets are quite good and there are more online (just Google: `handbrake presets <device>` if you're after something in particular.

Answer (score 0):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.berlios.de/) is the closest thing Ubuntu has in terms of a simple video-editor/muxer. For more full blown non-linear editing tasks there is also [kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) and [Cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/).

[image: Avidemux Screenshot]